# Configurable products in Catalog price rule

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

I have set up a catalog price rules that provide a bulk discount for products in certain categories. It works fine for simple products but unfortunately it seems to ignore configurable products. My rule is to have 15% discount on all selected categories. 
[image]

[image]

The associated products in the configurable products doesn't associated with any category, as those won't get displayed independently on front-end. If I bind all associated products to the category the price rule works.

**Do I need to bind all associate products to respective category?**

**Update:**
I have checked the catalogrule_product_price table and it have discount applied to product ID of configurable product and not to its associated simple product.

Comment: From what I have seen, since the simple products are more than likely not associated to the category, the rules skip over them. I would suggest adding a custom attribute to these associated simple products and include that as a condition for your rule. This should close the loop on them being skipped over.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally associated products should belong to the same category, configurable products have been placed to. Try to add simple to the same category, again set "Enable Discounts to Subproducts option to YES, apply the rule and do re-index. It should work

Comment: I have already set Enable Discounts to Subproducts option to YES. I have installed SCP (simple-configurable-product) extenstion too. Does it has any impact?

Comment: I tried one more time, but it is not working. Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you assign simple and configurable product into same category?

Comment: Adding the Simple Product to the category worked for me!